# How detect who create the thread by crash log?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash

When we receive some crash logs from Apple(TestFlight) which contain next some error:

```
 Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread.
```

for example or etc.
And we can't reproduce it under debug. It just happens. And we have only crash logs.
How to detect initial caller background thread by crash log only?
If it’s possible.

Comment: Do you have any execution issues (blue warning) in the issue navigator ?

Comment: Thread name in the crashlog usually represents the purpose, and might give you some insights onto what that thread actually is.

Comment: @PtitXav I'll try it, but I think it is possible from crash log

Comment: @EugeneDudnyk not always, if threads are anonymous.